# Why is there no "Text", but only "Text - Text mesh pro" when i try to add it in UI?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm currently learning how to create UI in Unity and when I want to add Text to the Canvas I right click it in Hierarchy, go to UI, and there is supposed to be "Text" option, but for some reason i can only see "Text - Text mesh pro". Maybe it's just new feature so they are combined now in one button, because I'm just learning what exactly is Text mesh pro, but is it supposed to be like this or my "Text" button is missing for some reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TextMesh Pro was a package that unity included. It is an improvement so it is recommended to use it.

Here you can read more:
https://blog.unity.com/games/textmesh-pro-joins-unity